# Valid Tree Traversal Base Cases and Pointers

Tags: tree, traversal

I am currently transferring my C++ skills into python. Regarding tree traversals, I was wondering what typical base cases are used to detect the end of a branch, since python does not use pointers. Normally in C++, you would pass the next node in by reference and check if it is NULL. The code sample attached below works; however, are there any potential areas for these if-statements that may cause errors for other samples? I read on another answer that you can check if self.data = None, but I am not quite sure why this works (it did not work for my example). Thank you!

```
 def inOrder(self, list3):
        if self.left:
          self.left.inOrder(list3)
        list3.append(self.data)
        if self.right:
          self.right.inOrder(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would define a Node in a tree.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.data = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

Now let's declare a node `temp` with value 10.

```
temp = Node(10)
```

Suppose you want to check whether `temp` is a leaf node or not, you would do something like,

```
if temp.left == None and temp.right == None:
    print('leaf node')
    return
```

Now if you have traversed past the leaf node and you are checking whether a node actually exists or not, you would do :

```
temp2 = temp.left
if temp2 == None:
    #abc
```

or

```
if not temp2:
    #abc
```

Not sure why `self.data = None` would work in which case you are declaring a node but not assigning any data to it.

That would probably fail while checking the leaf node since we are checking whether there is a left or right node present. It's good to create a Node with a value.